# Prevent JQuery datepicker date wrap around

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker used to select a birth date that has a range of 'present' to 100 years in the past.

```
$("#dateOfBirth").datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:+0"
});
```

Once the datepicker pops up, the user can 'scroll forward' through the years. Because of the date range, the next year after the present (2012) is a hundred years in the past (1912).

This behaviour causes confusion.

Is it possible to stop the dates wrapping around to the beginning to the date range?

Comment: *"I have a jquery datepicker used to select a birth date that has a range of 'present' to 100 years in the past."* So I guess this guy is SOL, then: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-wales-20295971 ;-) *(Wow: Him and about 10,000 others in the UK alone: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1214302/Number-Britons-reach-100-years-age-hits-10-000.html )*

Answer (score 3):

Change the approach and use [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) and [`maxDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate) properties instead of `yearRange`. `yearRange` is only for setting the content of that select, it doesn't limit the dates the user can input.

See how it looks here: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

In your case, you can probably just add

```
maxDate: "0"
```

to your options: http://jsbin.com/uducov/1 That tells the datepicker to make "today" the max date that can be picked, and it prevents the paging forward via the `>` button.

Notice that both `minDate` and `maxDate` accept a string with relative dates.